# nunit is not able executing tests giving ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, nunit

using nunit 3.0
visual studio 2013

but when trying to run test i am getting this on console

```
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

below is the code.

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace SampleCodeApp.NUnitTest
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class SampleCodeClassTest
    {
        [Test]
        public void SuiteSelectionTest()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("xxxx");
            String x = "e";
            Assert.That(x,Is.EqualTo("e"));
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't run the tests automatically. You need to use a [special plugin](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ab922d0-21c0-4f06-ab5f-4ecd1fe7175d) or run the tests from the nunit console. By the way, what you called `trying to run test` is only compilation from the source code.

Comment: @SergiiZhevzhyk , I have tried this already and installed the same

Comment: How do you run the tests?

Comment: @SergiiZhevzhyk  i run test by <CTRL+R>(Run Tests)

Comment: It works if you use Microsoft Unit Testing Framework, but it doesn't work for NUnit

Comment: Do you have the [NUnit3 Test Adapter](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0da0f6bd-9bb6-4ae3-87a8-537788622f2d) extension installed?  I believe the behavior you are seeing is similar to when you try to run NUnit 3.0 tests using the [NUnit 2.0 Test Adapter](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ab922d0-21c0-4f06-ab5f-4ecd1fe7175d).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problème with NUnit3 / NuGet / Visual Studio.

If you have NUnit installed as NuGet package, NuGet notify you that an update is available : NUnit3.
But you need also [NUnit 3.0 Test Adapter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit3TestAdapter/3.0.8-ctp-8) that is a prerelease version.

So NuGet don't notify you about it and [current release version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnitTestAdapter/) is not compatible with NUnit3.

So you can use NUnit3 / NUnit3TestAdapter prerelease or downgrade NUnit3 to NUnit 2.6.4.